# Chrome packaged app UDP sockets not working

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to get UDP sockets working for a packaged app using Chrome Canary (currently version 25).  I am pretty confused by the fact the [UDP example here](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network.html) conflicts with the [reference documentation here](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html).

The official example uses this line:

```
chrome.socket.create('udp', '127.0.0.1', 1337, { onEvent: handleDataEvent }, ...
```

In Canary using this line results in the error:

> Uncaught Error: Invocation of form socket.create(string, string,
>   integer, object, function) doesn't match definition
>   socket.create(string type, optional object options, function callback)

Not surprising since that matches the documented form of the function.  (I guess the example is out of date?)  OK, so I try this...

```
chrome.socket.create('udp', { onEvent: handleDataEvent }, ...
```

Canary complains:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 2. Property 'onEvent':
>   Unexpected property.

Now I'm confused, especially since this parameter is [undocumented in the reference](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html#type-CreateOptions).  So I just go with this:

```
chrome.socket.create('udp', {}, ...
```

Now it creates OK, but the following call to `connect`...

```
chrome.socket.connect(socketId, function(result) ...
```

...fails with this:

> Uncaught Error: Invocation of form socket.connect(integer, function)
>   doesn't match definition socket.connect(integer socketId, string
>   hostname, integer port, function callback)

...which is not surprising, since now my code doesn't mention a host or port anywhere, so I guess it needs to be in `connect`.  So I change it to the form:

```
chrome.socket.connect(socketId, address, port, function (result) ...
```

At last I can connect and write to the socket OK.  But this doesn't cover reading.

- Can someone show me a working example based on UDP that can send & receive, so I can work from that?
- How do I receive data since the example's onEvent handler does not work?  How do I ensure I receive any data on-demand as soon as it arrives without blocking?

Answer (score 8):

The Network Communications doc is not up-to-date. See the latest API doc: https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/socket.html. But the doc doesn't state everything clearly.
I looked into Chromium source code and found some useful comments here: [https://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/net/udp/udp_socket.h&q=file:(%5E%7C/)net/udp/udp_socket%5C.h$&exact_package=chromium](https://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/net/udp/udp_socket.h&q=file%3a%28%5E%7C/%29net/udp/udp_socket%5C.h%24&exact_package=chromium)

```
// Client form:
// In this case, we're connecting to a specific server, so the client will
// usually use:
//       Connect(address)    // Connect to a UDP server
//       Read/Write          // Reads/Writes all go to a single destination
//
// Server form:
// In this case, we want to read/write to many clients which are connecting
// to this server.  First the server 'binds' to an addres, then we read from
// clients and write responses to them.
// Example:
//       Bind(address/port)  // Binds to port for reading from clients
//       RecvFrom/SendTo     // Each read can come from a different client
//                           // Writes need to be directed to a specific
//                           // address.
```

For the server UDP socket, call `chrome.socket.bind` and `chrome.socket.recvFrom`/`chrome.socket.sendTo` to interact with clients. For the client UDP socket, call `chrome.socket.connect` and `chrome.socket.read`/`chrome.socket.write` to interact with the server.

Here's an example:

```
var serverSocket;
var clientSocket;

// From https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app_hardware.html
var str2ab=function(str) {
  var buf=new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
  var bufView=new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    bufView[i]=str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}

// From https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app_hardware.html
var ab2str=function(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
};

// Server
chrome.socket.create('udp', null, function(createInfo){
    serverSocket = createInfo.socketId;

    chrome.socket.bind(serverSocket, '127.0.0.1', 1345, function(result){
        console.log('chrome.socket.bind: result = ' + result.toString());
    });

    function read()
    {
        chrome.socket.recvFrom(serverSocket, 1024, function(recvFromInfo){
            console.log('Server: recvFromInfo: ', recvFromInfo, 'Message: ', 
                ab2str(recvFromInfo.data));
            if(recvFromInfo.resultCode >= 0)
            {
                chrome.socket.sendTo(serverSocket, 
                    str2ab('Received message from client ' + recvFromInfo.address + 
                    ':' + recvFromInfo.port.toString() + ': ' + 
                    ab2str(recvFromInfo.data)), 
                    recvFromInfo.address, recvFromInfo.port, function(){});
                read();
            }
            else
                console.error('Server read error!');
        });
    }

    read();
});

// A client
chrome.socket.create('udp', null, function(createInfo){
    clientSocket = createInfo.socketId;

    chrome.socket.connect(clientSocket, '127.0.0.1', 1345, function(result){
        console.log('chrome.socket.connect: result = ' + result.toString());
    });

    chrome.socket.write(clientSocket, str2ab('Hello server!'), function(writeInfo){
        console.log('writeInfo: ' + writeInfo.bytesWritten + 
            'byte(s) written.');
    });

    chrome.socket.read(clientSocket, 1024, function(readInfo){
        console.log('Client: received response: ' + ab2str(readInfo.data), readInfo);
    });
});
```